# CPU Usage while running command in command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, cpu-usage

I am looking for a way to output CPU usage percentage via the command line. I ran across this: wmic cpu get loadpercentage which gives me the desired percentage output however I want to test the CPU usage while running a certain command. Anyone have any idea? I tried doing it in a batch file but then realized that at the point i run wmic cpu get loadpercentage the CPU usage is no longer portraying the usage of the previous command. Ideally what I am looking for is something like this:

```
C:\> command xyz [ftp file.blah]
```

and then the file is uploaded correctly but the output is a percentage indicative of the CPU usage during the process. Not sure if I'm making myself clear. Hopefully something like this exists out there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of windows? XP/7? Server? Do you have access to powershell?

Comment: @AliGibbs Windows Server 2008 and Vista and yes I have access to powershell

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I knew about WMI - [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - but I must admit I did NOT know about WMIC - [WMI Command-Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  **:)**

I have found the following blog post that I think helps here:

**Rich's Blog - Get Process CPU Usage Using WMI**
http://www.techish.net/2009/03/get-process-cpu-usage-using-wmi/

In that blog post, the author uses the [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the CPU usage of a process (in several ways).

For instance, if the name of the running process is "iexplore" (Internet Explorer) then you would run:

```
wmic path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process where (Name=iexplore) get Name, Caption, PercentProcessorTime, IDProcess /format:list
```

Maybe you can do the following: have one open "Command Prompt" window where you run the "ftp command" and have another "Command Prompt" window where you run the `wmic path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process`query.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That would help but i need to do this 100s of times so it needs to be automated somehow.

Comment: Very helpfull, Thank you very much. +10 for `/format:list`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
wmic path win32_perfformatteddata_perfproc_process where Name="notepad" get Name, Caption, PercentProcessorTime, IDProcess /format:list
```